# How can I call search dialog on button click in android?

Tags: android, search

I am making a small application where I have to call search dialog on search button click
please give me simple code or simple tutorial because I have seen many example but I am not so expert to call the search dialog please help me 
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking about the hardware button or a button in your application?

Comment: I am talking about Hardware button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: (since we're talking about the hardware button)

Declare a searchable configuration: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html. There is an example at the bottom of the linked page.

Then create a searchable activity: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchableActivity

And then, for any activity that should react to the search button being pressed, do this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchDialog

Comment: Sir ihave used this code but it is not working  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        onSearchRequested();
    }

Comment: @Nitin -Disregard the first part of my answer, and read from UPDATE. I originally didn't see that you wanted to react to the hardware search button

Answer (score 2):

Override search button as :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH){
                //do, what you want
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i want when i click on Devise search button than it will show the Search widget.can you suggest any code for this.