# How can I call search dialog with an ImageView?

Tags: android

I have to call search dialog when I press a button into the activity or when I press an ImageView,  not with the hardware button like in this post:

[How can I call search dialog on button click in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744130/how-can-i-call-search-dialog-on-button-click-in-android)

Please if you have the code or a tutorial, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [docs for the search dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchDialog) under "Invoking the search dialog"

> ...However, some devices do not include a dedicated SEARCH button, so you should not assume that it's always available. When using the search dialog, you must always provide another search button in your UI that activates the search dialog by calling onSearchRequested()...

So you should be able to put `onSearchRequested();` inside your click listener to when the image is pressed this method call should launch the search dialog for you.

Comment: no problem, if it worked for you it is generally good to Accept the answer. See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more details